# Calculate pseudo random number based on an increasing value

Tags: swift, random

I need to calculate a pseudo random number in a given range (e.g. 0-150) based on another, strictly increasing number. Is there a mathematical way to solve this?

I am given one number `x`, which increases by 1 every day. Based on this number, I need to - somehow - calculate a number in a given range, which seems to be random.

I have a feeling that there is an easy mathematical solution for this, but sadly I am not able to find it. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the range depend on `x`?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: No, the range is fixed. I am using Swift.

Comment: Can you explain further how the random numbers will vary based on `x`?  For example, are certain numbers more likely to appear than others, depending on the value of `x`?

Answer (score 1):

One sound way to do that is to hash the number *x* (either its binary representation or in text form) and then to use the hash to produce the 'random' number in the desired range (say by taking the first 32 bits of the hash and extracting by any known method the desired value). A cryptographic hash can be used like Sha256, but this is not necessary, MurmurHash is possibly a good one for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you generate a random number, a seed value is used so that the same sequence of psuedorandom numbers isn't repeated. When a seed isn't explicitly given, many systems will use the time as a seed value.
Perhaps you could use x as a seed.
Here's an article explaining seeding: https://www.statisticshowto.com/random-seed-definition/